# sql table comparisons - postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables with some columns being the same:

**TABLE A**

```
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
+------+------+------+
|  1   |  aa  | ccc  |
|  2   | null | ccc  |
| null |  bb  | null |
```

---

**TABLE B**

```
|Col1  | Col2  | Col3| Col4 |
+------+-------+-----+------+
|  1   |  aa  | ccc  | aaaa |
|  2   | null | ccc  | cccc |
| null |  bb  | null | sss  |
|  4   |  bb  | null | ddd  |
```

I'd like to return the following:

```
|Col1  | Col2  | Col3| Col4 |
+------+-------+-----+------+
|  4   |  bb  | null | ddd  |
```

How do I check what rows from `table B` are in `table` A and also return `Col4` (from `table B`) where they match in the query.
I was using `EXCEPT` which worked great but now I need to have the outputs of `Col4` in the returned query results.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
SELECT  Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4
FROM    TableB
WHERE   NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT  1
  FROM    TableA
  WHERE   TableA.Col1 IS NOT DISTINCT FROM TableB.Col1
  AND     TableA.Col2 IS NOT DISTINCT FROM TableB.Col2
  AND     TableA.Col3 IS NOT DISTINCT FROM TableB.Col3
)
```

(Using `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` to say that columns with `null` are equal to each other.)

Comment: I've updated my tables to make things more clear. thanks for your help on this.

Comment: Updated my logic, you want rows in TableB that don't exist in TableA, right?

Comment: Bingo - this is exactly what I wanted - thanks so much :)

Comment: This worked brilliantly - is it possible to update this sql so that I can put in a case statement to find out which column is different. Lets say TableA.Col1 <> TableB.Col1 then 'Col1 different' and so on. Thanks so much for this - this is excellent

Comment: When I add a case statement to it, it takes forever to run - is there anyway of speeding it up?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is very easy: none of the rows from table 'A' are in table 'B'.
Those are separate tables and they have separate rows.

Now, if you want to find 'a row in table B, that has similar values in columns as a specific row in table A, you may do following:

```
select a.*,
       case when b.ctid is null then 'I AM A VERY SAD PENGUIN AND ROW IN B WAS NOT FOUND :('
            else b.col4 end as col4
  from table_a a
 left join table_b b on 
          ((a.col1 = b.col1 or (a.col1 is null and b.col1 is null)) and
           (a.col2 = b.col2 or (a.col2 is null and b.col2 is null)) and
           (a.col3 = b.col3 or (a.col3 is null and b.col3 is null))
          )
```

I assume that by 'similar' you would mean "if null appears in columns in both tables, the rows are still similar.

Notice the last insert into table_b i added - you are not guaranteed to find unique values of col4!:

[dbfiddle, modified version of VBoka's answer](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=349a66e1b7073b15381452030e3b8058)

Comment: when I say similar, I mean compare the first three columns but return all four columns where the rows in table b are not in table a (by just comparing the first three columns)

Answer (score 0):

If you have no duplicates within the `b` table, then the following handles `NULL` values rather elegantly:

```
select col1, col2, col3, max(col4)
from ((select coll, col2, col3, null as col4, 'a' as which
       from a
      ) union all
      (select coll, col2, col3, col4, 'b' as which
       from b
      )
     ) b
group by col1, col2, col3
having min(which) = 'b';
```